# Tensorflow: Custom CNN model accuracy depleted with training=False

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

I have trained a type of custom CNN model that looks like this:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = [Conv2D(filters=4,kernel_size=(12,12),input_shape=28,28,1),padding='same',activation='relu'),\
            BatchNormalization(axis=-1 if tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1),\
            Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(2,2),padding='same',activation='sigmoid'),\
            BatchNormalization(axis=-1 if tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1),\
            Conv2D(filters=1,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu'),\
            Conv2D(28, (9, 9), input_shape=(28,28,2), activation='sigmoid'), \
            BatchNormalization(axis=-1 if tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1), Conv2D(28, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid'), \
            Conv2D(14, (3, 3), activation='relu'), BatchNormalization(axis=-1 if tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1), \
            MaxPooling2D((2, 2)), Conv2D(56, (3, 3), activation='relu'), BatchNormalization(axis=-1 if tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1), \
            Conv2D(56, (3, 3), activation='relu'), MaxPooling2D((2, 2)), Flatten(),\
            Dense(200, activation="relu"), Dense(100, activation="relu"), Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='class_output')]

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        x = self.layers[0](inputs, training=training)
        for lyr in range(1,len(self.layers)):
            x = lyr(x, training=training)
```

and sometimes (not always!) the accuracy for testing drops to close to 0 when setting the `training`  variable to `False`.

If I test the trained model with something like:

```
def test_model(model, test_dataset, training=False):
    accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name='Test Accuracy')
    for (x, y) in test_dataset:
        test_preds = model(x, training=training) 
        accuracy.update_state(y, tf.argmax(test_preds, 1))
    print("{}: {}\n".format(accuracy.name, accuracy.result()*100))
```

I get for instance 0.018% with training=False but 98.9% with training=True. Any idea of what could cause this behavior? It does not actually seem fixed to batch normalization itself either as I first experienced similar behavior with Dropout layers instead of the batch normalization layers.

Comment: There could be many causes of low accuracy of the model. You may the Conv and BatchNorm layers in the following order instead -> `Conv2D, activation=None` -> `BatchNormalization` -> `Activation( 'relu' )`.

Comment: It is not a general low accuracy, when I run testing but with the training variable set to True I get 98.9% accuracy. The strange this is that it differs so much - normally you would expect accuracy to increase when setting training=False, at least for Dropout.

Comment: Any resolution?